# Cordova plugin to send data to javascript code from native android activity

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am doing a Hybrid Android app. My landing page will be a custom android activity which will have login and signup buttons. Once I click any of these buttons, another activity which is a subclass of CordovaActivity should be launched and load the corresponding html view in CordovaWebView of the activity. However I am facing issues in sending which html view (login/signup) should be loaded in the CordovaWebView upon the button click. That is how should i send some parameters from native android activity to javascript to identify login/signup ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old. But why not perform the condition check in your native activity, and save the required condition in your SQLite DB. As in :

```
if (buttonAIsClicked) {
    saveConditionsForButtonA();
} else if (buttonBIsClicked) {
    saveConditionsForButtonB();
}
```

Then upon load of your CordovaActivity, (JavaScript Code = ng-controller) check your DB for the value of the clicked button based on the saved value

```
var buttonClicked = getWhichButtonWasClicked(); //from DB
```

and act accordingly.

```
if (buttonClicked == buttonA) {
    $state.go(paramNameA);
} else if (buttonClicked == buttonB) {
    $state.go(paramNameB);
}
```

I know this is a hack. But that is how I did it, and it worked.

I hope this will be of help.